# Why does tf.Variable change value randomly?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have implemented a very basic operation graph to understand how Tensorflow works. However I am getting some unexpected behavior that I can't debug even though the program is so short:

All that the program is doing is creating a constant value `x` and a variable value `b` that get added.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy

x = numpy.asarray([1.0], dtype='float32')
b = tf.Variable(2.5, name="bias")

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:

    # Run the initializer
    sess.run(init)
    print('Input x pre-set to 1.0: {}'.format(x[0]))
    print('Input b pre-set to 2.5: {}'.format(b.eval()))
    output = sess.run(tf.add(x,b))
    print('x + b = {}'.format(output[0]))
```

The output of this program is:

```
Input x pre-set to 1.0: 1.0
Input b pre-set to 2.5: 0.0
x + b = 1.0
```

The value of `b` changes to `0.0`

Does anybody know what is happening here?

Comment: Couldn't reproduce the original error (before you edited the question), ran it a few times, always gave the correct result.

Comment: This new version also works okay in colab.research.google.com.

Comment: What is your setup? OS, version, TensorFlow version, are you running from Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: I am implementing other similar examples and always get the tf.Variable values assigned to 0.0 .. seems to be a systematic error in my setup. I am running this on tensorflow-gpu 1.4.0, on the Spyder console, Python 2.7, on Ubuntu 17.04

Comment: Same here, python 2.7 tensorflow-gpu 1.4 and when I copy/paste I get 3.5 as the result.

Comment: @PeterSzoldan The fact that you got different output as me made me think it was not a failure to understand Tensorflow. I restarted everything (Spyder) and now it seems to be working. If it were not for you trying to reproduce my results it would have taken me a long time of frustration. Thank you very much. If you answer claiming that this is NOT a tensorflow error I will accept it as the answer.

Comment: Okay thanks I'll write an answer. Please upvote David's comment too, he spent time on this as well.

Comment: @DavidParks will upvote too. Sorry I did not mention you, I posted my comment apparently at the same time as you wrote.

Comment: Okay posted answer, I also upvoted David.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce the original error (before you edited the question), ran it a few times, always gave the correct result. Same situation with the new version. Tried them in colab.research.google.com. As [David Parks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4790871/david-parks) tested it on the same setup as you, tensorflow-gpu 1.4, it seems that there must be something else going on here.

The code looks okay, both versions.

Try restarting you machine and retest. (c) Microsoft-style repair :)